# GDB - Find substring

Tags: gdb

I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define XXXVAL "Hello!\n"

void helloAction(){
        printf("Len: %d\n", strlen(XXXVAL));
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(XXXVAL);i++){
                printf("Char #%d = %d\n", i, XXXVAL[i]);
        }
        sleep(2);
}

int main(){
        while(1){
                helloAction();
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I ran it and try to debug with GDB.

```
(gdb) find  0x564d89488000, 0x7ffdae11c000, "Hello!\n" 
0x564d8948a01c
```

But:

```
(gdb) find  0x564d89488000, 0x7ffdae11c000, "Hello!"
Pattern not found.
```

I need a way how find not full(up to 0x00 byte) string. What's wrong and how resolve it ?

Comment: Enter `help find` in gdb, and you should see an example how to remove the null terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> `(gdb) find  0x564d89488000, 0x7ffdae11c000, "Hello!"`
> `Pattern not found.`

You are searching for `Hello!\0`, which indeed is not to be found.

You want to search for `Hello!`, and as @ssbssa correctly pointed out, `help find` shows you how to do that:

```
Note that this means for example that in the case of C-like languages
... and a search for a string "hello" will
include the trailing '\0'.  The null terminator can be removed from
searching by using casts, e.g.: {char[5]}"hello".
```

So you want: `find 0x564d89488000, 0x7ffdae11c000, {char[6]}"Hello!"`